# Sharding em MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Boa tarde, estou pensando em implementar um cluster para sharding usando o MongoDB, analisei as opções para shard key, e no meu caso o mais recomendável seria utilizar a política de zones (tags).
No entanto não encontrei nenhuma documentação dizendo que seria possível utilizar mais de um shard para servir a uma mesma zone. Alguém sabe se isso é possível?

Answer (score 1):

A primeira frase da documentação de sharding responde a tua pergunta: "In sharded clusters, you can create zones of sharded data based on the shard key. You can associate each zone with one or more shards in the cluster."

Antes de considerar usar sharding, você verificou que a tua necessidade realmente precisa disso? Como exemplo: hoje se você fizer um cluster no [atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud) ele habilita sharding somente em instâncias M50, que começam em 32GB de RAM e 160GB de HD.

As principais necessidades que te levam a considerar sharding são tamanho do banco de dados e/ou volume de leitura/gravação. Considerando uma configuração como a que mencionei acima, você já tem necessidade de sharding?

Faço essas considerações porque o sharding adiciona uma certa complexidade na manutenção do banco de dados [(backup, balanceamento de chunks, servidores de configuração)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/sharded-cluster-administration/) que vale a pena considerar antes se você realmente precisa.